# Sitecore Linkmanager always links to Web Database link even from page editor

Tags: sitecore, page-editor

Hi am trying this code

```csharp
public String GetItemUrl(Item item)
{
    Sitecore.Links.UrlOptions urlOptions = (Sitecore.Links.UrlOptions)Sitecore.Links.UrlOptions.DefaultOptions.Clone();
    urlOptions.SiteResolving = true;

    return Sitecore.Links.LinkManager.GetItemUrl(item,urlOptions);
}

ViewBag.thisurl = GetItemUrl(item)
```

and then from cshtml

```
a href="@ViewBag.thisURL" .....
```

When I click on the link, this will always point to CD database and I am not able to edit in page editor. I need to edit the target after i click the link in page editor. Can some one suggest me?

Comment: By CD database, do you mean 'web'?

Comment: Yes it is web database

Comment: To rule out the basics, have you checked the connection strings for the Master database?

Comment: View the Sitecore config using _http://[yoursite]/sitecore/admin/showconfig.aspx_ verify if `hostName` or `targetHostName` is set on your `<site>` node. Also check the Link Provider in `linkManager` node and ensure `alwaysIncludeServerUrl="false"`

Comment: I did. The weird part is, in page editor, it does not get clicked, I have to right click and then open then it goes to web DB page. There I cannot edit.   it should come as the page-editor link, the link type itself becomes https:.... web DB link for the target page.

Comment: Also, are you running multi-site instance? Is the link you are clicking on in "another site"?

Comment: I doube checked and it's perfect as you suggested. I have single instance but multilingual. To test I am just using single site and only one language  for now.

Comment: and the line Sitecore.Links.LinkManager.GetItemUrl(item) is always returning the web DB url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use SiteResolving, are you running CMS and CD on one server? so they have the same web.config and the hostnames in the sites web.config section point always to CD. [SiteResolving explained](https://briancaos.wordpress.com/2012/03/28/sitecore-links-in-multisite-solutions-siteresolving/)

There are multiple options.

1) Make a condition and set SiteResolving off in page edit mode. something like this:

```csharp
public String GetItemUrl(Item item)
{
  Sitecore.Links.UrlOptions urlOptions = (Sitecore.Links.UrlOptions)Sitecore.Links.UrlOptions.DefaultOptions.Clone();

  if (Sitecore.Context.PageMode.IsPageEditor || Sitecore.Context.PageMode.IsPreview)
  {
    //depend on your site configuration this is a idea
    urlOptions.SiteResolving = false;
  }
  else
  {
    urlOptions.SiteResolving = true;
  }

  return Sitecore.Links.LinkManager.GetItemUrl(item,urlOptions);
}
```

2) Create your own Sitecore LinkProvider to change the behavior see this example [Create a Sitecore LinkProvider to use different LinkManager configurations](http://sitecore.stockpick.nl/english/change-linkmanager-config.aspx)

Comment: You can simplify slightly to `urlOptions.SiteResolving = !Sitecore.Context.PageMode.IsPageEditor`, but same difference :)